# Getting a precise execution time of a MySQL statement

Tags: mysql

Right now the results indicate
 X rows in set (0.00 sec). So I am wondering if there's a way I can get the time in more than 2 decimal places.

Comment: I would rather be interested in slow queries in my system than knowing the time taken by each query. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html

Answer (score 8):

Execute `set profiling=1` before running your statement, then obtain timings with `show profiles` query .

See [SHOW PROFILES syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html) for more details, including how to find out what actions are using time inside your query, such as checking permissions , logging etc.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know - exactly what you want is not possible. You can, however, modify your query to force not to use any cache `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, name FROM customer` and run that 100 times and then divide your answer by 100 :)

Good luck!