# PDO statement execution time

Tags: mysql, pdo

How can I determine the time a statement took to execute on the database server with PDO?

I am using MySQL.  Most MySQL client utilities seem to be able to show how long a query ran on the server, irrespective of the total time which includes the transfer of the result over the network.  This leads me to believe that the native MySQL API offers this information somewhere.  Is it exposed in PDO?  If so, how can I get to it?

**Note:**  I have found a [MySQL query method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100474/getting-a-precise-execution-time-of-a-mysql-statement), but would prefer not to execute more statements just for this if the execution time is already kept track of somewhere else.  If it isn't, then I will fall back on this method.

Comment: If you want to expressly *exclude* network transport time, then the profiling command as given in that linked question is probably your only option, at least for PDO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a precise execution time of a MySQL statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100474/getting-a-precise-execution-time-of-a-mysql-statement)

Comment: @Johan, this isn't a duplicate of that question at all.  I was asking if PDO exposed a method.  It seems the answer is that it doesn't, but that is no reason to assume that this question is a duplicate of one unrelated to PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no way to do this at the PDO layer.  In retrospect, this makes quite a bit of sense, since PDO is abstracting all of the DB-specific features away.